# How do I know how old my betta is?

Tags: health, fish, betta

I recently adopted 2 beautiful female Betta fish! I also have one male. I noticed that the girls are a lot more active than the male.

As they swim around in their tanks, Mr.Rainbow whom I have had in my home since December 2017 either hides or sleeps but mostly sleeps. He also refuses to eat.

As I have been studying him, I noticed he is a lot bigger than the girls. Is he dying of old age?

Comment: Do you mean 'December 2016' instead? Currently, Mr.Rainbow wouldn't have been born for 5 months :P

Comment: In order to get an answer you should clarify your question by editing it. You're bringing up a lot of causality speculations, see f.ex. your last sentence: studying, bigger size than females and dying of old age have nothing incommon. Why did you bring them together in one sentence?